# Multipoint peer with WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

I'm developing a web application that want to share the posts that one user posted in one topic argument via webRTC. 
The problem is that webRTC allow only one-to-one peer connection. 
What can i do for solve this problem using webRTC?
I need that my information is transfered broadcast to the other peer that are connected in the same room.

Comment: Why would you go about doing it this way?
That said, I am assuming you are using the data channel for that purpose. In the same way that you are connecting the data channel 1:1, you can connect it to multiple people in the group with multiple separate connections.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need some signaling server like [easyrtc](/questions/tagged/easyrtc), which packages some really awesome functionalities. One of those is multy-party videocalls.

If you want to read more about, and see some cool demos check https://easyrtc.com/ and https://demo.easyrtc.com/demos/

Answer (score 0):

After you establish the connection via signalling server, you can open the `DataChannel` and make the transfer that you said..